# Iterate Through Cursor, moveToNext() Does Not Appear To Work

Tags: android, sqlite, iterator, cursor

I'm running into a bit of a problem. I am trying to iterate through a cursor to pull out the needed data. However the `moveToNext()` methods does not seem to move the cursor past the first position. It will move to the first row of results no problem, but it seems like it will not go past that first row and returns true every time. Resulting in an infinite loop. Here is my code:

This methods adds a new item to the database:

```
public List<Items> getAllItems() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    DatabaseParser parser = new DatabaseParser();

    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName.ITEMS.getName(), null);
    List<Trip> items = parser.cursorToListOfItems(result);

    Cursor moreResults = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName.MORE_ITEMS.getName(), null);
    List<MoreItems> moreItems = parser.cursorToListOfMoreItems(moreResults);

    items = parser.combineListOfItemsWithListOfMoreItems(items, moreItems);

    db.close();
    result.close();

    return items;
}
```

This is the `cursorToListOfItems()` methods that pulls the data out of the cursor and puts it into an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Items> cursorToListOfItems(Cursor data) {
    List<Items> items = new ArrayList<Items>();
    Items item = null;

    if (data.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            item = new Items(DataFactory.getDatabaseItemsData(data));
            items.add(trip);
        }
        while (data.moveToNext());
    }

    return items;
}
```

Now my problem is that in `cursorToListOfItems()` the call to `moveToNext()` always returns true which causes my app to crash.
**Thing I Have Tried**

1. I have tried different ways of iterating through the cursor with no change.
2. I also deleted the app files and uninstalled then reinstalled the app and I still have the same problem.
3. I also connected the debugger to take a look into the cursor and I can see the marker indicating which row its at go from `0` to `1` indicating that it successfully went to the first row and then the second. But after that every time the loop executes the position stays at 1. indicating that it never goes past the second row to find out if there is any more data to execute and just returns `true` which starts the infinite loop.

I've now run into a brick wall on this. Any help, answers or suggestions that lead me to a solution are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have checked the logs and there are no exceptions thrown. Only logs about the ANR I eventually get. But I will post the logs here just to be safe:

> 07-15 16:00:02.368       60-309/system_process I/ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/.MainActivity } from pid 441
>   07-15 16:00:02.518      441-441/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/dalvikvm: GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 27K, 52% free 2589K/5379K, external 3399K/3716K, paused 34ms
>   07-15 16:00:04.007      441-443/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 701K, 50% free 3421K/6727K, external 3842K/4311K, paused 3ms+3ms
>   07-15 16:00:05.127      441-443/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 698K, 44% free 4285K/7623K, external 3842K/4311K, paused 3ms+4ms
>   07-15 16:00:06.448      441-443/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 866K, 40% free 5298K/8775K, external 3842K/4311K, paused 3ms+4ms
>   07-15 16:00:07.468        60-90/system_process I/InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{406fa4b8 com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit.SplashActivity paused=true}.  5005.0ms since event, 5004.8ms since wait started
>   07-15 16:00:07.468        60-90/system_process I/WindowManager: Input event dispatching timed out sending to com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit.SplashActivity
>   07-15 16:00:07.503      441-444/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/dalvikvm: threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
>   07-15 16:00:07.557      441-444/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/dalvikvm: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
>   07-15 16:00:08.498      441-443/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 940K, 36% free 6405K/9991K, external 3842K/4311K, paused 3ms+5ms
>   07-15 16:00:08.577        60-90/system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit (com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/.MainActivity)
>           Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
>           Parent: com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/.SplashActivity
>           Load: 0.36 / 0.27 / 0.14
>           CPU usage from 47129ms to 2463ms ago:
>           4% 60/system_server: 3.7% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 1142 minor
>           1.6% 349/com.android.launcher: 1.3% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 3315 minor
>           0% 40/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
>           0% 135/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 4 minor
>           +0% 439/sh: 0% user + 0% kernel
>           +0% 440/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
>           +0% 441/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit: 0% user + 0% kernel
>           13% TOTAL: 11% user + 1.8% kernel
>           CPU usage from 542ms to 1077ms later:
>           92% 441/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit: 92% user + 0% kernel / faults: 207 minor
>           71% 441/grourp.itruckit: 71% user + 0% kernel
>           20% 443/GC: 20% user + 0% kernel
>           5.5% 60/system_server: 1.8% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 1 minor
>           3.7% 90/InputDispatcher: 1.8% user + 1.8% kernel
>           1.8% 61/HeapWorker: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
>           1.8% 73/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 0% kernel
>           98% TOTAL: 92% user + 5.5% kernel
>   07-15 16:00:10.187        60-73/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/.MainActivity
>   07-15 16:00:10.208        60-73/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit (pid=441): user's request
>   07-15 16:00:10.228       60-126/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit (pid 441) has died.
>   07-15 16:00:10.238        60-90/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '406fa4b8 com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
>   07-15 16:00:10.238        60-90/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '406fa4b8 com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit.SplashActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>   07-15 16:00:10.268       60-307/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{406fa4b8 com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit.SplashActivity paused=true}

**EDIT 2**
Here is your requested logs:

> 07-15 16:13:19.738    1710-6219/system_process I/ActivityManager: Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/.MainActivity } from pid 9583
>   07-15 16:13:19.908    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/Database: dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/databases/itruckit, flag = 6, file size = 11264
>   07-15 16:13:19.908    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit D/Database: dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/databases/itruckit, mode: wal, disk free size: 2538 M, handle: 0x3496e8
>   07-15 16:13:23.552    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   07-15 16:13:23.562    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-position: 0
>   07-15 16:13:23.602    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   07-15 16:13:23.602    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-position: 1
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-position: 1
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-position: 1
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-position: 1
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   07-15 16:13:23.622    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-position: 1
>   07-15 16:13:23.632    9583-9583/com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit I/log-count: 2
>   ...keeps repeating...

**EDIT 3**
Here is the code for `DataFactory.getDatabaseItemsData(data)`:

```
public static final DatabaseHelper.DatabaseTripData getDatabaseTripData(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return createTripData(cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getInt(1), cursor.getInt(2),  
            cursor.getInt(3), cursor.getInt(4), cursor.getString(5), 
            cursor.getString(6), cursor.getLong(7), cursor.getLong(8), 
            cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11));
}

return null;
}
```

And all `createTripData()` does is take the data from the cursor and creates a wrapper class to hold it.

Comment: post what the error is

Comment: I posted the logs for you.

Comment: `items.add(trip);` what is `trip`? Should that be `item`?

Comment: I changed some of the method names to more discrete names... yes item is trip...

Comment: Add some logging. Print the value of `data.getCount()` before entering the loop, and print `data.getPosition()` on each iteration.

Comment: ok added the requested logs. I also noticed that while it does go from position 0 to position 1 that it still takes only the first row in the database. My list fills up with only data from the first row of the database. The second row of the database is not showing up.

Comment: The two rows are at positions 0 and 1, so that part is correct. The problem is, as you state, it doesn't seem to be terminating the loop.

Comment: Maybe you have repositioned the cursor to first row when call `DataFactory.getDatabaseItemsData(data)`

Comment: I didnt think of that... I have to get heading home now though. I'll check on that as soon as I get home and let you know what I find. Thanks for the assistance so far.

Comment: Change the loop to just `while (data.moveToNext()) { ....}`, and remove the initial `moveToFirst()`. It's much simpler that way.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. I looked at the code in `DataFactory.getDatabaseItemsData(data)` and I'm pulling out the data from the cursor in that method. Which makes me wonder, is there a limit to the number of times you can pull the data out of a cursor? I'll post the code for that method also.

Comment: As I suspected you move the cursor to the fist row **again** `if (cursor.moveToFirst())` remove this check. See @CL answer

Comment: Thanks for all the help getting this figured out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The best way to thanks is upvote my comment, if you think that was useful

Comment: Sorry I sometimes forget we can upvote comments as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `getDatabaseItemsData` calls `moveToFirst` *again*.

You should change `getDatabaseItemsData` so that it assumes that the cursor is already positioned on a valid record, i.e., just remove the `moveToFirst` call.

Answer (score 1):

Your app creches because your operation are in UI thread(reading from db), you should use AsyncTask or Thread.

```
ANR in com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit (com.eyephonegrourp.itruckit/.MainActivity)
Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
```

ANR Error: Activity Not Responding.

Comment: Thats not it sorry. I only have two rows in the table I am accessing there is no reason for it to take 5 full seconds to pull out 2 rows of data. I do plan on moving them to a different thread before the app is released, but this should be taking less than 2ms.

Comment: maybe you have an infint loop some where like "getDatabaseItemsData" debug the code. and check the file '/data/anr/traces.txt', using command "./adb pull path_to_file location_to_save"